# Inline Assembly - AT&T Syntax - Error on LLVM compile (not w/GCC though)

Tags: macos, assembly, inline-assembly, att

So I'm trying to include this assembly w/in my Objective-C executable:

```
__asm volatile(
               "pushl %[a5]\n\t"
               "pushl %[a4]\n\t"
               "call %%ebx\n\t"
               "addl  $8, %%esp\n\t"               
               : "=a" (result)
               :  "b" (FuncPtr), "a" (MyVal), "d" (MyVal2), "c" (MyVal3), [a5] "r" (iOut), [a4] "r" (a4)
               : "memory"
               );
```

If I use the GCC compier, it compiles fine, but then at the return of the function using the above an error is thrown due to GCC throwing in a nice ud2a instruction vs. just throwing an error at compile time (caught in gdb).

If I use the Apple LLVM compiler, it yells at me for the line "push %[a4]\n\t" with the error: "Unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix"

Does anyone have any idea what this means?  I'm at a complete loss on how I need to adapt the above to function properly.

Note: This is what it's trying to do:  Push a5, a4 onto the stack.  Move FuncPtr to ebx, move MyVal to eax, move MyVal2 to edx, move MyVal3 to ecx, and call ebx.

Comment: Figured it out, %%esp needs to be *(%%esp)

Comment: Please leave an answer if you have solved the problem.